# Equation for a heart

Tags: calculus, geometry, circles

I’m trying to determine the equation for a heart starting from the unit circle. I figured a way to do it is to go from progressively closer shapes. What is the equation for shapes A-D? The very first equation I started from was the bottom half of the unit circle, which is $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$, however I didn’t know how to proceed from there to derive the following shapes.

[image]

Comment: You might find this useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid

Comment: (and a good online graphing calculator: https://www.desmos.com/calculator)

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? I find something like $(x^2+y^2-1)^3 - x^2y^3 = 0$ is close enough to the traditional heart symbol. See mathworld's entry on [heart curve](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html) for other choices.

Comment: I see the graphs for the final heart, but are there equations for graphs A-D?